# How to implement select box in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is no select box option in Bootstrap 3. I am able to get select box only in Twitter Bootstrap. Which control i have to use to implement a responsive select box using Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can use select2 with bootstrap css: http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/